# How to publish a simple machine-learning approach that cannot compete with the state of the art?

Tags: publications, writing, publishability

I am proposing an approach which is simpler than current approaches, but does not come close to the state of the art on benchmark metrics. But, I think my approach is still cool and much simpler in implementation. I want to avoid comparing my approach to the state of the art in the research paper I am writing. How do I go about this situation?

Comment: Post on arXiv ?

Comment: why mention a comparison to 'state of the art' at all?

Comment: You'll need to say something about the trade-off between simplicity and poorer performance on benchmarks. Random guessing is way "simpler than the current approaches, but does not come close to state-ot-the-art benchmark metrics." OK, that's a joke. But you'll need to show that your approach is not a joke, and that will probably require saying how far it falls short on those benchmarks and then discussing why its simplicity compensates for the shortfall.

Comment: But, won't the reviewers just look at the table and say that it's below state-of-the-art? What is the best strategy to convince them?

Comment: You need to state, very clearly, especially in the abstract, your reasons for considering your approach interesting despite it's weaknesses.

Comment: In determining whether your approach is novel, you will need to do a deep literature search. I've been following machine learning, off and on, since the early 1970's. My impression is that many simple approaches were implemented, evaluated, and overtaken by more complicated but more effective approaches. What you are doing may have been published 40 years ago.

Comment: I am sure this is not the case because my approach is grounded in recent technologies.

Comment: And recent technologies are firmly grounded in older technologies. Which are often based on what some really smart people did early on.

Comment: To take an arbitrary example, probably irrelevant to your research, GPUs are new, Some things for which one would use a GPU today have been done previously on vector or SIMD parallel processors. "It uses a GPU" is insufficient to show a technique does not predate GPUs.

Answer (score 9):

If you try to avoid the benchmark metrics comparison, it is going to be the 900 pound gorilla in the back of the mind of everyone reading your paper.

The alternative is to deal with it from the start. You obviously think there are reasons why your technique is interesting despite its benchmark metrics. You need to communicate those reasons. They should be first mentioned in the abstract. That way, readers are more likely to suspend thinking about the benchmark metrics issue in favor of thinking about what makes the technique interesting.

At some point in the paper you will need to present some metrics, in order to support a claim that the simplicity of your technique outweighs the metrics for some situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, will doing what you suggested convince reviewers at top-tier venues? It might convince middle-tier reviewers though.

Comment: @shaunpollock Remember I have no idea what your technique is, what problems it might apply to, what your basis is for thinking it is novel and interesting, or anything else about it other than that it does not match state-of-the-art on common benchmarks. If you want an informed opinion on what sorts of venues might accept your paper, run it by trusted researchers in your area.

Comment: Also, you probably won't convince top tier reviewers if it's *actually not convincing.*  Omitting important comparisons won't fix that.  On the other hand, if there are merits to your method *despite* not being uniformly the best, an accurate and candid comparison is how you'll convince them.